# Calculating a path from one state to another

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have the following data structures:

```
class State
- Map[String, Integer]: properties
```

State describes the system at a particular point in time.

```
class Transition
- Map[String, Integer]: requirements
- Map[String, Integer]: adjustments
```

Transition describes a potential way to mutate State:

- Both maps are keyed with the same keys as properties within State
- requirements defines the minimum values for some subset of State's properties (satisfying these makes the Transition legal)
- adjustments says how applying the transition affects the State's property values. Positive values increase the value of that property while negative ones decrease it. Each transition's adjustments define the result of applying that transition for one unit of time. Applying a transition must not result in a property value becoming negative.

Given the input of:

- start: State
- goal: State
- transitions: List[Transition] (all the potential transitions that are available to be applied)

I would like an output of:

- plan: List[Transition]

This would be the minimal sequence of (legal) Transitions, the application of which result in the Target state from Start state.

This seems like it might be a well defined algorithmic problem, something that gets taught in CS degrees all over but I cannot figure out what keywords would bring it up.

Is there a name for this class of problems and how do you solve it?

Comment: You may be able to specify this as a [Minimum-cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) with states as verticies and adjustments as edge costs.

Comment: This sounds like a graph theory problem. Some keywords that could help: graph traversal, weighted path problem.